# How can I call 2 functions in the same custom module?

Tags: 7, hooks

In my template file I have 2 links like

```
if(mytest){
  print l(t('Action 1'), 'my_first_link/'.$id);
}else{
  print l(t('Action 2'), 'my_second_link/'.$id);
}
```

In my custom module I have

```
function myModule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['my_first_link'] = array(
    'title' => 'First function',
    'page callback' => array('myModule_first_function'),
    'page arguments' => array(1,),
  );
  $items['disableproject'] = array(
    'title' => 'Second function',
    'page callback' => array('myModule_second_function'),
    'page arguments' => array(1,),
  );
  return $items;
}
function myModule_first_function($url_argument){
  print('url_argument = '.$url_argument);
}
function myModule_second_function($url_argument){ 
 print('url_argument = '.$url_argument);
}
```

My first link works fine but my second doesn't!

It gives me a 404 error!

How can I solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add 'access arguments' to your call:

```
$items['disableproject'] = array(
  'title' => 'Second function',
  'page callback' => array('myModule_second_function'),
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access arguments' => array('some permission'),
);
```

Or you can add a custom access callback:

```
$items['disableproject'] = array(
  'title' => 'Second function',
  'page callback' => array('myModule_second_function'),
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access callback' => 'some_access_callback_function',
);
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I used **'access callback' => 'user_access',** and it works fine

Comment: You don't need `'access callback' => 'user_access'`, that's the default. If you leave it out, that will do the same thing. It's `access arguments` that matter in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define the access arguments true, use this if you want this link to be accessible by anyone else use what Jaypan has suggested. BTW I believe that you have flushed your drupal cache after making changes to hook_menu

```
$items['disableproject'] = array(
  'title' => 'Second function',
  'page callback' => array('myModule_second_function'),
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access arguments' => TRUE,
);
```

Comment: Thank you Sir.. It's just accessible for admin. I keep your solution for next tasks :) Thanks again

Comment: This will result in an error - `access arguments` must be an array. You probably meant `access callback`.

Comment: I tested with **'access arguments' => TRUE,** and it's ok

Comment: It's not @A.Sana, clear the cache and you'll see the error message. It's very well documented: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x. _"access arguments": An **array** of arguments to pass to the access callback function_. Emphasis mine